# Show the following function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

$$f(x) = \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-\sqrt{1 + t^2}} dt$$

Explain why this function is differentiable at each $x \in [0,\infty)$ and compute $f'(x)$.

I know that $f'(x) = e^{-\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}^2}} - e^{-\sqrt{1 + (-\sqrt{x})}^2} = e^{-\sqrt{1 + x}} - e^{-\sqrt{1 + x}} = 0$. However, I am having a hard time explaining why it is differentiable at each $x$.

I tried to apply the limit definition $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$. However, it becomes pretty nasty since it has integrals within the limit. I'm not convinced this is the way to show it just because it doesn't really get me anywhere.

My next idea seemed golden to me.

I can state the Fundamenetal Theorem of Calculus as follows:

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable and define
$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} g(t) dt$$
$\forall x \in [a,b]$. Then, $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is continuous at some point $c \in [a,b]$, then $F$ is differeitable at $c$ and $F'(c) = f(c)$.

Our function $f$ has no discontinuities, so its set of discontinuities is of measure $0$. So it is integrable. $f$ is continuous $\forall c$ in the domain because it is an exponential, which is always continuous. So, this would mean $F$ is differentiable everywhere.

BUT, our function is $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. not an interval of the form $[a,b]$. Is this option out of the picture as well then? It seems so close!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your computaiion of $f'$ is wrong. Apply chain rule for finding the derivative.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't think I understand because that is how the fundamental theorem of Calculus works here. That reply also doesn't help me see the issue with showing it.

Comment: You have to multiply each term by derivative of $\sqrt x$. The derivative of $\int_a^{g(x)} f(t)dt$ is not $f(g(x)$. It is $f(g(x)) g'(x)$. Do you know chain rule for differentiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $e^{-\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ is defined and continuous everywhere, it has an antiderivative $F(t)$ which is defined and differentiable everywhere, with $F'(t) = e^{-\sqrt{1+t^2}}$.  Since $F$ is defined and differentiable everywhere, so is the function $H(t) := F(t) - F(-t)$.  The fundamental theorem of calculus says that

$$\int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt = F(\sqrt{x}) - F(-\sqrt{x}) = H(\sqrt{x})$$

which is differentiable for $x \in (0,\infty)$ (not on $[0,\infty)$), because a composition of two differentiable functions is differentiable.

The derivative of this function is given by the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg( F(\sqrt{x}) - F(-\sqrt{x}) \bigg) = F'(\sqrt{x}) \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} - F'(-\sqrt{x}) \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ $$ = e^{-\sqrt{1+x}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + e^{-\sqrt{1+x}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{1+x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: I know you are mad because your answer was downvoted LOL.  I did say in my answer that the differentiability was only on $(0,\infty)$ but not on $[0,\infty)$ and did not prove it.  Maybe I will say it's left to OP as an exercise.

Comment: @D_S Differentiabilty on $(0,\infty)$  is trivial  since  composition of two differentiable functions is differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

The question is wrong. The function is not differentiable at $0$. By definition $f'(0)=\lim_ {x \to 0+} \frac 1  x  \int_{-\sqrt x}^{\sqrt x} e^{-\sqrt {1+t^{2}}}dt=2\lim_ {x \to 0+} \frac 1  x  \int_{0}^{\sqrt x} e^{-\sqrt {1+t^{2}}}dt$. An applicatioin of L'Hopital's Rule shows that this limit is $\infty$.

Comment: There is no 1/x in front of the integral.

Comment: @DominicBlanco The derivative is $\lim \frac {f(x)-f(0)} {x-0}$. The $x$ in the denominator comes from this definition.

Comment: Just modify your original interval of differentiability to be $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: @ChaoticGood The question asks for differentiability on $[0,\infty)$. You cannot omit $0$ So my answer is correct and the other approved answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I am the one who upvoted your comment! I agree with your assessment, and I was instead replying to Dominic. My apologies.

Comment: @ChaoticGood Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If we set the relation such that: $-\sqrt{x}\lt a \lt \sqrt{x}$, we can rewrite the integral function in this form: $$f(x)=\int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{a}e^{-\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt \space +\space \int_{a}^{\sqrt{x}}e^{-\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$$ Then we can take the derivative of it by applying the chain rule: $$f'(x)=0-\Biggl(\frac{e^{-\sqrt{1+x}}}{-2\sqrt{x}}\Biggl)\space + \space \frac{e^{-\sqrt{1+x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}-0=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{1+x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$$ The function is differentiable on the open interval $(0,\infty).$